# In Magento 2.2.5, logo is not changing in custom mail

Tags: email, magento-2.2.5, logo

In Magento 2.2.5, I am adding some custom mail functionality. It is triggering with the content. But the mail logo is not changed. [Here](https://pastebin.com/B6HRmGhg) is mail template content.

Changed mail logo in `Admin panel - theme edit -> Transactional mail`. Even changed in the theme folder too. It is not affecting. Any mistake am doing.